# Navigate from unknown to known environment

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hai, I want to use a turtlebot to navigate from unknown to unknown environment. The scenario is like this:

1. Robot wait in a known environment (eg: house).
2. Someone ask the robot to follow him or her until outside the known environment i.e. outside the house. Lets say its new position is car.
3. Now the robot need to get the position near the car and navigate back into the house. For example to the kitchen.

Can someone suggest me a method on how to do the no 3 problem?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255385/navigate-from-unknown-to-known-environment/) by [Azwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29367/azwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just saying, if you want people to take the time to make a clear and complete answer,you should take the time to ask your question clearly. With the mistake in the first sentence and the formulation of your question, it took me more than 5minutes to really understand what you are asking for...

About your issue, in my opinion, you should make some research on odometry methods and find one adapted to your application.
A SLAM method would allow you to map your previously unknown environnement but you don't need that much information, you just need to keep track on your position in your unknown environnement to be able to go back to your the known part of your world later. Odometry techniques will allow you to do so.

---

Originally posted by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) with karma: 267 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0